# Java Buffered Reader to map

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to reader from a file which is stored as below for a quiz;

With the identifier and question identifier on the first line, then a question heading with the question next, answer heading with answers and finally the selected answer.

I'm trying to read the file and then store it using a HashMap

```
16 TF
Question
Because an ArrayList is an indexed collection, you can access its elements using a subscript. 
Answer
False
True
Selected
1

258 MC
Question
Fill in the blank. A Node is generally defined inside another class, making it a(n) ____ class.
Answer 
Private 
Inner 
Public 
Internal 
Selected 
2

37 L5
Question
How would you rate your programming skills? 
Answer
Excellent
Very good
Good
Not as good as they should be
Poor
Selected
-1
```

My code:

```
  Quiz newquiz = new Quiz();
    List<String> newArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<Integer, String> newquizmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    BufferedReader BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader('file.txt'));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = BR.readLine()) != null) {
        String nuquiz[] = line.split("   ");
        BufferedReader.readLine();

       newquiz.newquestionid = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);



             lines.add(line);
               newquizmap.put(newquiz.newquestionid, newArray.toString());


            line = BufferedReader.readLine();

            System.out.println(newquizmap);
        } 

    } BR.close();
```

I know this isn't right, I don't even think it's close but I'm really struggling with this could anyone give me any help?

EDIT:

```
          Quiz newquiz = new Quiz();
    List<String> newArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<Integer, String> newquizmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    BufferedReader BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader('file.txt'));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = BR.readLine()) != null) {
        String nuquiz[] = line.split("   ");
        BufferedReader.readLine();

       newquiz.newquestionid = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);



             lines.add(line);
               newquizmap.put(newquiz.newquestionid, newArray.toString());


            line = BufferedReader.readLine();

            System.out.println(newquizmap);
        } 

    } BR.close();
```

Tried this code and it appears to fill every map key with every value?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a java object as hashmap value. Create a new class to contain the below attributes (modify to handle all your question use cases):

```
private String questionId; //This will hold question Id - TF    
private String question; //This will hold the Question - Because an ArrayList is an indexed collection, you can access its elements using a subscript. 
    private List<String> choices; //This will hold the choices - Private Inner Public Internal 
    private Integer selectedChoice; //This will hold the answer
```

Include parameterized constructor and other required methods in the class.

Parse the file, loop through the contents, create an object of this new class and add to hashmap with "id" as key and "pojo object" as the value.

Note: Please fix a few other issues in your java code (formatting, coding standards like variable names starting in uppercase, QuestionSet, StdOut.. etc)